# Google Maps API v3 (PHP & Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I would like to display multiple markers (up to 20 at least) on the Google maps via Javascript. The data which comes in an array is in PHP.

Upon running the code, the Google map only plots the last co-ordinates in the array. Can you guys enlighten me why? Following are the codes (Sorry if this is albeit messy as i'm a novice. thanks for any help in advance):

```
$link ="http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=trace&host="."$ip_address";
$link_traceroute ="http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=a15e8640c34837e4d402df55d7fd5e059e50d0d407d285a7a3b2ccbf85e1a234&ip=";

$response = file_get_contents("$link", false, $context);

$pieces_traceroute = strchr ($response, "$ip_address is from");
$split_pieces_traceroute = str_replace("Trace","$$$",$pieces_traceroute);
$better_pieces_traceroute =(explode("$$$",$split_pieces_traceroute));

$raw_data = strip_tags($better_pieces_traceroute[1]);
$split_data = (explode(" ",$raw_data));

for ($i=0; $i<count($split_data);$i++)
{

$checker= valid_ip($split_data[$i]);

    if ($checker != null){
    $response_traceroute = file_get_contents("$link_traceroute"."$split_data[$i]", false, $context);
    $pieces_traceroute = (explode(";",$response_traceroute));
    $Cord1 = $pieces_traceroute[8];
    $Cord2 = $pieces_traceroute[9];
    echo $Cord1.nl2br("\n");
    echo $Cord2.nl2br("\n");
    ?>

    </style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $Cord1;?>, <?php echo $Cord2;?>);
     var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      title:"Hello World!"
  });

  // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
  marker.setMap(map); 
  }
```

Comment: Can you dump/print out the array?

Comment: here u go :)
Erm as previously requested the following are my results are my co-ordinates upon echoing. They came from the variables $Cord1 and $Cord2. 38.9048 -77.0354 38.9048 -77.0354 38.9048 -77.0354 44.9631 -93.4943 38.9048 -77.0354 38.9048 -77.0354 38.9048 -77.0354 38.9048 -77.0354 38.9048 -77.0354 38.9048 -77.0354 39.9 116.413 39.9 116.413 39.9 116.413 39.9 116.413 29 120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doesn't need to loop the full js part (including `<script>` `initialize`). You get only the last value because of that. Try something like this instead...

```
// Assume we have $locations variable which hold array data
<script>
function initialize() {
    var centerMap = <?php echo json_encode($locations[0]) ?>;
    var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>;
    var centerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(centerMap[0], centerMap[1]);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: centerLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    });

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Erm, ok i edited ur code and make it worked. may i know how do u show the markers live? as in it will plot out the marker once and flush to browser and on and on?

Comment: Above code is transfering your php array, into json structure(by this line : `var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>;`), so it will be easier to work with that in js. Then you itterate the json instead itterate your php array in loop statement (which were the markers made/plot and attach them to your map, started by line `for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { `)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is little bit weird. You have `count($split_data)` times included 'google maps library', closed tag `</style>`, created `map`, initialized function `initialize`. Why? Are you sure that `count($split_data)>=20`? Have you dumped it?  Why don't separate php-part and js-part? You could get all places to be displayed on the map using ajax, or you could even from needed array of obects(each object could contain `lat`, `lng`, `name`, etc) in php. Then make `$j_array=json_encode($array)` in php-part to convert it to string and `var places=<?php echo $j_array; ?>;` in js-part to make object again. And than you are to work with array of objects in js. It is much easier and obviously. Refactor your code. It is messed.

I hope it will be helpfull. Sorry for messed english, I treid to be clear.

Comment: Erm the number of co-ordinates i have is dynamic. it doesnt have to be 20. I hard coded it so as to check whether Google Maps would traverse my array and plot them which apparently it didnt. Erm, i'm not familiar with ajax and this code is a sample Google provided. I just integrated it into my php array coding such that it will plot the various co-ordinates. Dunno whether i answered your question but ya :(